# Integrate virtual keyboard into extjs 4.2 form

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I'm adding the virtual keyboard from http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard to a text field of an extjs 4.2 form.

It basically works, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5VN8/1/

1) My first question is: is this really the best way to connect them? Looks ugly to me with a timer instead of events to keep the extjs value up to date.

Plus I can't overcome the following two issues:

2) the keyboard icon is wrapped to a new line. It should instead be at the end of the field, on the right side, just as in the examples here: http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard

3) The field focus doesn't work. I have it in a show listener. Even when wrapped in a window.setTimeout() it doesn't work, so it's not a timing issue. No error is thrown.

Here is a copy-paste (stackoverflow's rules). I'll keep both places up to date.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%',
         },
        items: [{
            xtype:'textfield',
            name: 'string',
            fieldLabel: 'String',
            maxLength:30, enforceMaxLength:true,
            allowBlank: false,
            listeners: {
                show: function(field) {
                    //focus the field when the window shows
                    field.focus(true, 1000); //TODO: doesn't work, no error
                },
                afterrender:function(cmp){
                    cmp.inputEl.set({ //see http://jsfiddle.net/4TSDu/19/
                        autocomplete:'on'
                    });

                    //attach the keyboard
                    //because it modifies the dom directly we need to hack it to 
                    //inform extjs (really, ext has no such listener option?)
                    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                        try {
                            var newValue = cmp.inputEl.dom.value;
                            var oldValue = cmp.getValue();
                            if (newValue != oldValue) {
                                //only do it then, cause it also moves the cursor 
                                //to the end and that sucks.
                                cmp.setValue( newValue );
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            //form was removed
                            window.clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    }, 100);
                    // see http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard
                    VKI_attach(cmp.inputEl.dom); 
                }
            }
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Alert string',
            handler: function() {
                var stringField = this.up('form').getForm().findField('string');
                alert(stringField.getValue());
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can attach a listener to the keyboard and when the user clicks on a VKI key you trigger the textfield change event.

   ```
   Ext.getBody().on({
   mousedown: function (ev) {
       if (ev.target.tagName === 'TD') {
           // We trigger change event only on textfield with the focus
           if (document.activeElement) {
               if (document.activeElement.id === cmp.inputEl.dom.id) cmp.fireEvent('change');
           }
       }
   }, 
   delegate: '#keyboardInputMaster'
   });
   ```
2. This is because ExtJS 4 writes the input field with "style=width:100%".
   An easy way is to add a negative margin to the textfield

   `fieldStyle: 'margin-right:-40px'`
3. Weird ExtJS behaviour. You must focus the input element, not te thextfield component

   ```
   Ext.defer(function () {
       cmp.inputEl.dom.focus();
   }, 100);
   ```

You can see the whole solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/EGbLn/3/

Comment: unfortunately, code formatting and bullets don't really play well with each other: the code needs 8 spaces (vs. 4 normally) and ctrl-K is no help ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that was my first post.

Comment: you're welcome :-) Just check my edit, I'm not overly familiar with javascript, so might have made a mistake while formatting

Comment: This still looks like a hack to me. Why not simply attaching the event to the DOM element itself?

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid timers. Use regular dom event listeners instead.

   ```
   afterrender: function (cmp) {
       ...

       // simply attach this to the change event from dom element
       cmp.inputEl.dom.addEventListener('change', function(){
           cmp.setValue(this.value);
       });

       ...
   }
   ```
2. (answered already by Samy Rancho)

   ```
   fieldStyle: 'margin-right:-40px',
   ```
3. Again, avoid timers and anything similar. Simply add this:

   ```
   afterrender: function (cmp) {
       ...

       //focus on field
       cmp.inputEl.dom.focus();

       ...
   }
   ```

Find updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5VN8/11/